# Cannot show progress bar in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

When i run this code, screen is all black and does show the progress bar. I have no idea why. Can someone help me or explain why nothing is showing on the screen. Thanks in advance !

progressbar.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ProgBar(BoxLayout):
    pass

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ProgBar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

progressbar.kv file

```
<ProgBar>:

    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas: 
        Color: 
            rgb: .45, .28, .5
        Rectangle: 
            pos: self.pos 
            size: self.size 


    Label: 
        text: '[size = 40px]Progress Bar 1 (at .25)'
        color: .5, 0, .5, 1
        markup: True


    ProgressBar: 
        value: .25
        min: 0
        max: 1
        pos_hint: {'x':.1} 
        size_hint_x: .8


    Label: 
        text: '[size = 40px]Progress Bar 2 (at .55)'
        color: .5, 0, .5, 1
        markup: True


    ProgressBar: 
        value: .55
        min: 0
        max: 1
        pos_hint: {'x':.1} 
        size_hint_x: .8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what part of your code do you indicate that the .kv load? Well nowhere do you do it, by default kivy loads the x.kv if the name of the class that inherits from App is xApp that is not met in your case so you must load it explicitly using the Builder through the [`Builder.load_file()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_file) method :

```
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file("progressbar.kv")


class ProgBar(BoxLayout):
    pass


class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ProgBar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```